# Compute interaction from mean and confidence interval of a 2 x 2 design

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value

Is there a way to compute the interaction effect and its p value of a 2 by 2 design if I only know their estimated mean and confidence interval:

|  | Time 1 | Time 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Condition1 | 19 [16, 21] | 22 [20, 25] |
| Condition2 | 17 [14, 20] | 19 [16, 22] |

I was told the p value of interaction was .094, but I don't know how to compute this.
Thank you so much for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like Condition1 and Condition2 are two levels of a single classification variable, and Time 1 and Time 2 represent repeated measurements on the same subjects.  If I have this correct you could write your model in the following form

$$\hat{\mu}=\hat{\text{int}}+\text{condition}\cdot\hat{\beta}_1+\text{time}\cdot \hat{\beta}_2+\text{condition}\cdot\text{time}\cdot\hat{\beta}_3$$
where $\text{condition}=I\{\text{Condition 2}\}$ indicates Condition 2 (0 otherwise) and $\text{time}=I\{\text{Time 2}\}$ indicates Time 2 (0 otherwise).  In this parameterization, $\hat{\text{int}}$ is the estimated mean for Condition 1 at Time 1.  Based on your table the parameter estimates are

$$\hat{\mu}=19+\text{condition}\cdot(-2)+\text{time}\cdot (3)+\text{condition}\cdot\text{time}\cdot(-1)$$

We can even approximate the estimated standard errors of the means in your table by assuming a Wald test was performed so that $\text{UCL}=\hat{\mu}+1.96\cdot\hat{\text{se}}_{\hat{\mu}}\implies \hat{\text{se}}_{\hat{\mu}}=(\text{UCL}-\hat{\mu})/1.96$, where $\text{UCL}$ is the upper confidence limit.

The snag we run into is that we do not have the estimated covariance between the regression coefficients.  If we naively assume they are all independent we arrive at a negative standard error for $\hat{\beta}_3$.  Without the additional information on the covariance between the regression coefficients I do not think it is possible to reconstruct the p-value for the interaction effect $\beta_3$.  Let me know if I have made any mistakes and if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, Geoffrey! May I ask how did you get (-1) for condition * time ?

Comment: Condition1, Time1: $\hat{\text{int}}=19$.  Condition2, Time 1: $\hat{\text{int}}+\hat{\beta}_1=19-2=17$.  Condition1, Time 2: $\hat{\text{int}}+\hat{\beta}_2=19+3=22$.  This implies that $\hat{\beta}_3=-1$ so that Condition2, Time 2: $\hat{\text{int}}+\hat{\beta}_1+\hat{\beta}_2+\hat{\beta}_3=19-2+3-1=19$.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks again for your answer.